# How to access a type with same fully qualified name in 2 different DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, datagrid

I need to refer to both the assemblies `PresentationFramework.Classic` and `PresentationFramework.Luna` and I have a situation where I need to use the `Microsoft.Windows.Themes.DataGridHeaderBorder` type. But this gives error as both the assemblies have this type defined. 
I mean, I can do with referring to any of them (Classic or Luna) for this type,   it's just a simple Datagrid, where I need to check if the `DataGridHeaderBorder` is clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of situation that [external assembly aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) are intended to address.  You can also specify the alias for a reference using the "Aliases" property in the reference's properties sheet in Visual Studio if command line compilation isn't your thing.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx for a full example.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above option but ran into problems as this does not work with WPF projects and has been reported as a bug - [Bug Link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615953/reference-aliases-are-ignored-on-projects-containing-some-xaml-files#details). I tried the workaround but I am facing this error - **The extern alias 'Classic' was not specified in a /reference option**

Comment: This was an excellent help, only if I wouldn't be using WPF. I have read a lot on this and came across that this is the actual solution to handle this kind of situation but this solution does not work for WPF application and has been marked as a bug by MS. This would be resolved in 4.5 release. Great article though. I have finally removed one of the assembly references and trying to do without it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
using Clasic = PresentationFramework.Classic;
using Luna = PresentationFramework.Luna;



namespace Test1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Clasic.Microsoft.Windows.Themes.DataGridHeaderBorder bClassic;
            Luna.Microsoft.Windows.Themes.DataGridHeaderBorder bLuna;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It says _The type or namespace name 'PresentationFramework' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_, though I have included both the assembly references.

Comment: Is it namespaced properly? Verify / validate the source Class and Luna assemblies and make sure the namespaces match up and aren't rooted in some other namespace.  The Assembly Name does not have to match the namespace, although this is typically the case.

Comment: @Art - I have verified and the namespaces aren't rooted in some other. Both the assemblies root namespace is Microsoft.Windows.Themes. Have you tried this with WPF cause mine is a **WPF application**?