# IObservable ambiguous reference error

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, mscorlib

I'm using Reactive extensions in my WPF application. And while using it I'm getting below ambiguous reference error.

```
The type 'System.IObservable<T>' exists in both 'mscorlib.dll' and 'System.Reactive.dll'
```

I tried with fully qualified name also and tried [this url](http://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2010/10/14/reactive-framework-conflict-solved/) as well, but didn't get any luck. I'm using .NET 4.0 version of Reactive Extensions.

My Code:

```
using System; // mscorlib.dll
using Rx = System.Reactive;

public Rx.IObservable<int> BytesReceived { get { return _bytesReceivedSubj; } } // Not valid as IObservable is in System namespace of System.Reactive.

public IObservable<int> BytesReceived { get { return _bytesReceivedSubj; } } // With this I'm getting ambiguous reference error
```

[image]

Any idea how can i resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory.  You have 2 libraries that both have a definition of `IObservable` so you have to clarify which one you are trying to use.

Comment: Both are in "System" namespace, and in the same form I'm using System from mscorlib also for EventHandlers and all. So how I can give fully qualified name here for IObservable? If I used System.IObservable then it will again give me ambiguous reference error.

Comment: You don't have an extra `using System.Reactive;` in there somewhere do you?

Comment: @Kevin, No I don't have extra System.Reactive declaration in my form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you reference `IObservable`, either use

```
System.Reactive.IObservable<T>
```

or

```
System.IObservable<T>
```

UPDATE>>>

Ahhhh, now that you've added the image, I see your problem. You have two System.IObservable classes... what idiots those Reactive guys are!

Anyway, take a look at these posts:

[How to access a type with same fully qualified name in 2 different DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264155/how-to-access-a-type-with-same-fully-qualified-name-in-2-different-dlls)

[Extern alias walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx)

It's not pretty, but it should help you.

Comment: That's not the reason ... he must be referencing the wrong versions after upgrading or something.  @JimWooley is right.  Calling people idiots, especially when they aren't, is inappropriate.

Answer (score 8):

When you say you are using the .Net 4 version of Rx, which version of Rx are you using? 1.1 or 2.x? If using 2.x, you shouldn't have a reference to System.Reactive, but rather System.Reactive.Core. I suspect you upgraded this project from .Net 3.5 but didn't update all of your necessary references. Make sure the version of Rx you are using isn't for Silverlight 4 or .Net 3.5 (which didn't have IObservable/IObserver in the core).

It may be easiest if you just remove the references to reactive and have nuget re-add them for you using the Reactive Extensions - WPF Helpers version. Note: You may need to change your imports for classes using Rx to import System.Reactive.Linq if you are using the older version that had the extension methods in the older System.Linq namespace.