# System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe: ambiguous reference

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

```
CrossBleAdapter.Current.WhenStatusChanged().Subscribe(obj => { });
```

I'm getting the following error for the subscribe method

> /Users/sarath/Developer/Workspace/GCH Mobile
> App/Gogch.iOS/TMAirController.cs(57,57): Error CS0121: The call is
> ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
> 'System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe(System.IObservable,
> System.Action)' and
> 'System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe(System.IObservable,
> System.Action)' (CS0121) (_SmartFHR.iOS)

How can I resolve this?

### Edit

Upon further investigation I found that ObservableExtensions exists both System.Reactive.Core and System.Reactive. I can't remove either because other packages depend on it.

### Update

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

I found the problem. I was using System.Reactive version 4.0.0 and System.Core.Reactive version 3.0.0. Once I changed core version to 4.0.0, problem solved.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928507/iobservable-ambiguous-reference-error

Comment: Probably something wrong with references, you have two different assemblies with the same types. You need to get rid of one reference

Comment: I found that ObservableExtensions exists both System.Reactive.Core and System.Reactive. I can't remove either because other packages depend on it.

Comment: Then use alias https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ansonh/2006/09/27/extern-alias-walkthrough/

Comment: @HeisenBerg please edit your question to include the additional information you gave in your comment. (comments are ephemeral and may be quickly cleaned)

Comment: I found the problem. I was using System.Reactive version 4.0.0 and System.Core.Reactive version 3.0.0. Once I changed core version to 4.0.0, problem solved. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction @AccessDenied