# Two Nuget Packages references conflicting reactive libraries

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

My problem is very similar to that mentioned in this post:

[System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe: ambiguous reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792781/system-observableextensions-subscribe-ambiguous-reference)

I would like to use the "GraphQL for .NET" nuget package and the "Plugin.BluetoothLE" package.

"GraphQL for .NET" references System.Reactive.Core and "Plugin.BluetoothLE" references System.Reactive

As stated in the other post:

> Upon further investigation I found that ObservableExtensions exists both System.Reactive.Core and System.Reactive.

How do I resolve this? "Plugin.BluetoothLE" has System.Reactive 4.0.0 and "GraphQL for .NET" has System.Reactive.Core 3.1.1.

Is there a way for me to upgrade System.Reactive.Core inside GraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent tried this below but you can see on their [github](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive#v40-changes) it was described as breaking change and there is workaround. see the highlighted sentence below.

**v4.0 changes**

Due to the overwhelming pain that fixing #205 - Implement assembly version strategy caused, we have refactored the libraries into a single library System.Reactive. To prevent breaking existing code that references the v3 libraries, we have facades with TypeForwarders to the new assembly. **If you have a reference to a binary built against v3.0, then use the new System.Reactive.Compatibility package.**

**Supported Platforms**
Rx 4.1 supports the following platforms

.NET Framework 4.6+
.NET Standard 2.0+ (including .NET Core, Xamarin and others)
UWP
Notably, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8 and legacy PCL libraries are no longer supported.

**v3.0 breaking changes**

The NuGet packages have changed their package naming in the move from v2.x.x to v3.0.0

Rx-Main is now System.Reactive
Rx-Core is now System.Reactive.Core
Rx-Interfaces is now System.Reactive.Interfaces
Rx-Linq is now System.Reactive.Linq
Rx-PlatformServices is now System.Reactive.PlatformServices
Rx-Testing is now Microsoft.Reactive.Testing
This brings the NuGet package naming in line with NuGet guidelines and also the dominant namespace in each package. The strong name key has also changed, which is considered a breaking change. However, there are no expected API changes, therefore, once you make the NuGet change, no code changes should be necessary.

Comment: Seems like the right thing to do but now I'm getting an error: 

"Error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, referenced by `System.Reactive`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, or remove the reference to `System.Reactive`. (XA2002)"

I've added that nuget package to all of my projects to no avail.

Comment: didn't quite get me there but good work went into the answer and it isn't wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

One of two ways

1. Try setting Nuget to get the minimum version to the lowest one listed by your packages.
2. Split out the operations into separate libraries and manage the differing package version specific to library.

Comment: The packages would not let me change the version of the referenced package so 1 won't work. 

2 would work but would be too much maintenance.